# No serializer found for empty beans error after changing FetchType to LAZY

Tags: java, jpa

I changed the `FetchType` of all my `@ManyToOne` to `FetchType.LAZY` from the default `FetchType.EAGER`.

So an entity looks like this for example:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class DailyEntry {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private long id;

  // more attributes

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Project project;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Employee employee;
}
```

But im getting the following error, each time I do a request to get the entities:

```
ERROR Type definition error: [simple type, class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->de.hiqs.dailyentry.DailyEntry["project"]->de.hiqs.project.Project$HibernateProxy$cmEQxiMb["customer"]->de.hiqs.customer.Customer$HibernateProxy$BV240DdJ["hibernateLazyInitializer"])
```

As the error states, i can disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS and everything will work fine. But is that what I am supposed to do or what is the usual way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To enable lazy loading in ToOne relationships Hibernate is putting a proxy instead of the the real object in the reference.

In order to serialize your bean you have to make sure that the references are initialized.  For example by calling the getter or using EntityGraph:

https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/